# With the javadoc target in Apache Ant, is it possible to make all external links open in a new window

Tags: apache, ant, javadoc

The Apache Ant [javadoc target](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html) allows a `<link>` attribute to link to external javadocs. I would like these javadocs to open in a new window (like `target="_blank"`), but the link attribute doesn't accept a `<target>` attribute that would allow me to do something like this. Is there some other way to do this apart from manually editing the links after they are generated?

Comment: Maybe use a javascript: in the href to open in new window. Dont know of an ant setting for this.

Comment: Can a JS file be injected into the Javadocs during generation (making it a do-it-once sort of thing)? If not, then just adding target="_blank" too all external links after generation would be just as good a solution if not better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "bottom" element can be used in javadoc ant task. 
It injects html code into each files.

```
<javadoc .....>
    <!--
    .....
    -->
    <bottom>
    &lt;script&gt;
    for(var i in document.links) {
        var link = document.links[i];
        if (link.href.indexOf('http') === 0) { 
            link.target = '_blank';
        }
    }
    &lt;/script&gt;
    </bottom>
</javadoc>
```